# In topology Dense in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

There exists $A \subset \Bbb Q$ such that $\Bbb Q-A$ is infinite and $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

True or false ?

Comment: What do you want to say ? it's completely unclear what you are asking ?

Comment: I am asking is that

Comment: Above statement is true or not ?

Comment: Do we have to guess what the statement above means ? You didn't define anything ? What are $R$, $Q$ ? Which topology do you use on those spaces ...

Comment: I have some short of idea but not fully

Comment: You won't have any answer if you don't make a small effort to ask a clear question... Also, if you have an idea of the answer, you have to explain what is your idea... we are not here to do your homework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb {N}$

Answer (score 0):

A well-known and natural example: consider $\mathbf D$,  the set of decimal numbers, ;.e;  the set of fractions with denominator a power of $10$ in irreducible form.